# Parsing text using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have to parse table data which is present at the url below:
http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GOOGL.O

I am interested in parsing out the names in the first table that lists all the people under the summary section.

I have read the url into nokogiri but unable to extract as i am new to nokogiri. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Show the code and we can help you.

Comment: @ A.D. I am not quite sure how to traverse the nodeset returned by nokogiri, thats why seeking help.

Comment: would be good if you can show me how it could be done.

Comment: first you get html page using doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GOOGL.O'))  then after read specific node or xapth data.

Comment: I need to see the code to understand. Im a newbie to nokogiri

Comment: I have just read the doc using nokogiri thats it. confused about the way ahead.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" along with the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We appreciate that you're new to Ruby, however on Stack Overflow we expect to see your effort. SO isn't a "write code for me" site, nor is it a "write a tutorial for me" site. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 discusses this. I'd recommend rewriting your question, showing the minimal code that demonstrates a problem you're having. Nokogiri's tutorials are good starting points. There's a lot of questions and answers for Nokogiri here on SO that you should read through too as those answer your question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
```

At first I open the source and use nokogiri to parse it and get a nokogiri document.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GOOGL.O"))
```

Now I select the elements you are interested in only via an xpath.

```
elements = doc.xpath('//*[@id="companyNews"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/h2/a')
```

Last step is to clean the text of each element from newlines and tabs and return the names as unique values.

```
elements.map{|officer| officer.text.strip}.uniq
# => ["Eric Schmidt", "Sergey Brin", "Lawrence Page", "Ruth Porat", "Sundar Pichai", "David Drummond", "John Hennessy", "L. John Doerr", "Roger Ferguson", "Diane Greene", "Ann Mather", "Alan Mulally", "Paul Otellini", "Kavitark Shriram", "Shirley Tilghman"]
```

Comment: Rather than toss out code, please explain what it does. The goal is to teach and instruct. It's akin to teaching someone to fish, rather than hand them a fish.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that starting with Nokogiri isn't very easy.

Since you didn't provide any code, I won't give you a complete solution, but a basic structure :

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def company_bosses(abbreviation)
  doc  = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=#{abbreviation}"))
  name = doc.xpath('//div[@id="sectionTitle"]').text.strip
  puts name
  table = doc.xpath('//tbody[@class="dataSmall"]')
  puts table.to_s.include?('Eric Schmidt')
  # Keep looking for the desired data inside 'table'!
  # ...
end

company_bosses("GOOGL.O")
```

It outputs :

```
Alphabet Inc (GOOGL.O)
true
```

The data you're looking for is in `table` variable inside the method. It is a [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet).

The Nokogiri [documentation](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) is good enough, and [Firefox inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) is a great help when trying to understand an HTML structure (provided the browser hasn't changed it).

Comment: Be very careful using a browser-based inspector. They rely on the markup as massaged by the browser, which can be different than what was actually sent to the browser. Using `wget`, `curl` or even Nokogiri from the command-line will show the actual markup that hasn't been touched/mangled/changed by a browser.

Comment: @theTinMan: Very interesting, thanks. The interface is really easy to use, and it makes understanding the structure much easier. Is there any equivalent tool for raw markup?

Comment: There are many programming editors that help when viewing markup, but their goal is different than Firebug or similar plugins so they won't offer all the same functionality. vim/gvim or Sublime Text are my tools of choice but there are plenty of others out there, just don't trust what a browser says.

Comment: @theTinMan : Any vim plugin you'd recommend?

Comment: I'd recommend the normal HTML plugin but your needs might vary.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GOOGL.O'))
puts doc.xpath("//div[@id='companyNews']/div[@class='module']/div[@class='moduleBody']/table/tbody/tr/td/h2[@class='officers']/a").text
```

Comment: Please explain what this does. You want to teach the OP so they don't have to ask again.

Comment: I have tried using the next, first methods to extract the second column but to no avail. Can someone tell me where i am going wrong?